# Pingdom test shows wierd js files attached to my website

Tags: javascript, php, html, pingdom

I ran a pingdom speed test on one of the inside pages of my website. It says i have 8 JavaScript files served from static.xx.fbcdn.net. I have no idea about these js files and i cant find anything useful on google about these files. Anyone has an idea?
I have come to know that these files are coming from facebook servers but they look suspicious. I am not so well versed in web development so cant figure out what this is.

https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/y4/r/zruGfUBUjGV.js
https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yO/r/LilJx2Avt8k.js
https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yd/r/JZaIleexme7.js
https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/ye/r/AVdu22kOEsU.js
https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3i6Vs4/y0/l/en_US/Wg1xqGzMah2.js
https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3iaQY4/yE/l/en_US/Po8O49311iD.js
https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3ik7T4/y4/l/en_US/1yn9j_M3cyR.js
https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3ik8i4/yB/l/en_US/LmN_URVC6HY.js